# Explain why 3.15>3.14

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for asking a trivial question. But how do you prove this given that the definition of a fraction is a point on the number line, and a whole number m is smaller than another whole number n if m is to the left of n. And now suppose we define a fraction A to be smaller than another fraction B, if A is to the left of B on the number line.

Comment: Because $315>314$, so that $\frac{315}{100}>\frac{314}{100}$?

Comment: Thanks. I thought I needed to use move different segments on the number line for a specific sequence of nths! :)